# Get ProgramFiles path using WinRT API from C++ library

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, porting

Can you please provide alternate WinRT API for the below win32 API `SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, buffer, CSIDL_PROGRAMS, 0)`?

StorageFolder class will only give application specific path .

Thank You

Comment: Um, `CSIDL_PROGRAMS` is not the ProgramFiles path. It's the Start menu.

Comment: I don't think that's something you're allowed to get with a WinRT api